# Arquillian files 'in classpath' even though not defined in WebArchive when run tests

Tags: jboss-arquillian

Testing Arquillian 1.9.final TOMCAT-EMBED-7 container, and I'm getting questionable results around creating a WebArchive for testing.

In /src/main/resources, I have several configuration files that I ***do not*** want to use when running the integration tests, instead I want to provide named ones stored in /src/embed-itest/resources.

```
        org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.Filter x = Filters.exclude(".*Test.*|.*xml|.*properties");
        WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap
            .create(WebArchive.class, "mytest.war")
            .addPackages(true, x, "com.myapp")
            //and some other additions
```

Then at the end of the srhinkwrap process, I add the specific test files I want to use:

```
    File n = new File("src/embed-itest/resources/test-log4j.properties");
    webArchive.addAsResource(n,"log4j.properties");
```

However, the behavior is still running as though it is using the /src/main/resources/log4j.properties.  I've verified the _DEFAULT_DEFAULT_mytest.war really does have the test-log4j.properties content as log4j.properties, but running the tests the behavior is that of /src/main/resources/log4j.properties.  (and this is true for other configuration files, such as camelContext.xml I've tried to override).

Anyone have some insight please?  I was hoping to leverage the ability to create a custom WebArchive with specific files in the archive to more precisely test, but the actual behavior seems to be as if it was the 'standard' created war limiting what I thought was a great capability of arquillian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that yo are using the Tomcat embedded approach, which means you are sharing the JVM of your tests with your Tomcat instance. I suggest you try with managed or remote mode.

Comment: That may be helpful to help manage expectations.  Unfortunate in that I was trying to avoid 'creating' a tomcat instance (even on the same machine, such as a Jenkins build server and possibly different tomcat 7.0.47 v 7.0.55 builds for different projects) so was pleased with the embed option and it placing tomcat files in the /target/ location for on-the-fly setup.

Comment: Then what you can do is use Arquillian Cube so your Tomcat instance is dockerized: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-cube

Comment: p.s. thanks for the followup comment around arquilian cube!